# jquery traversal question

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given:

```
<div>
   <div id="div1">
     <input type="radio" .. />
   </div>

   <div id="div2">

   </div>

   <div id="div3">
     <button type="button">a button</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

So, I am currently in the context of the `<input>` via its click event.  I need to traverse this (using parent / children somehow) to select the button in `div3` (without using a class, id etc) and enable/disable it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use classes/IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any information about the *logical relation* between the elements, I can only make assumptions.

#### If the structure will remain exactly the same, then:

```
$(this).parent().next().next().find('button').attr('disabled', true);
```

#### If the target div is always the last element in the container, then:

```
$(this).parent().siblings(':last').find('button').attr('disabled', true);
```

#### If there is only ever one `<button>` in the container, then:

```
$(this).parents().eq(1).find('button').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Though I ***highly*** recommend using some sort of class/ID to help out because DOM traversal can be brittle.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
$('#div1 > input').click(function(){
    $('#div3 > button').attr('disabled','disabled')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Html hierarchy never changes, then this will work.

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        var elm = $(this).parent().parent().find('div').eq(2).find('button');
    });
 });
```